# Dynamics NAV - SQL Server Report Builder - CommandText property has not been initialized

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-nav

I would like to start by describing what I am trying to do. I am working in Dynamics NAV 2015 attempting to create a custom report layout using Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder. The way it works is I am in NAV, I choose a custom report, and then I click 'Edit Layout'. The Report Builder pops up on its own and allows me to start working.

The problem is that, even if I have a completely fresh report with nothing on it, I cannot preview the report. Instead I get the following error:

```
ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized
----------------------------
Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet_Result'.
----------------------------
An error has occurred during report processing.
----------------------------
An error occurred during local report processing.
```

The strange thing is that if I do work and save it, then go back into NAV and print the report, it works fine. I just can't preview it while I'm working on it in the Report Builder.

Does anyone know why 'CommandText' would not be initialized automatically? Or where I would go to initialize it? I feel something may not be set up properly, but I can't find anything anywhere that has been helpful.

Comment: Is it possible for you to run the query in isolation (SSMS perhaps?) to ensure that the parameters are good and not malformed or unexpected values that may cause the query to crash out for any reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preview does not work in the Report Builder when editing a layout for Dynamics NAV. The dataset is not available to the report builder at the time of the design.
These reports do not connect directly to SQL or Reporting Services.

You need to save and run the report through NAV so it can populate its dataset. There is a preview in the Report's request page.

I usually leave the report layout open > Save layout > Return focus to NAV > It will prompt to import the layout > Ctrl + S > Ctrl + R.

Comment: Oh, that's disappointing! Is this from personal experience or did you happen to read about this limited functionality somewhere? It seems to waste a lot of time having to save it, import it, and run it, just to check if something works or not. You would think they would tie the systems together a bit better than this.

Comment: It's not documented anywhere, from what I can tell. Based on how the data set is generated from NAV, I can understand why it doesn't work -- it's not a simple SQL report that would normally be developed in SQL Report Builder. RDLC is better than the Classic Report Designer. You get the hang of the shortcuts while developing :)